# sqlite query to find sum of all values in a column

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum

This column is the price in sqlite.I am using `SELECT SUM(price) FROM example;`
But the value is not correct its just 5 digit number followed by 67 number and 6 zeros and 1, eg: 34,456.670000001  . The column is created as a VARCHAR .I have tried numeric(100) and Integer but the value still remains the same .Please guide me through as I am a noob in db.Thanks again.I would really appreciate the help.

```
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
126,334,123.32 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
75,334,123.32 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
52,334,123.32 
2,442,887.21
255,165.11 
3,889.02 
622.43 
916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
77,245.67 
104,245.00 
332.98 
6,875.21 
12,225.14 
52.54 
402.82 
32,875.32 
160,334,123.32 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,334,123.00 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,334,123.32 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,334,123.32 
2,442,887.21
255,165.11 
3,889.02 
622.43 
916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
77,245.67 
104,245.00 
332.98 
6,875.21 
12,225.14 
52.54 
402.82 
32,875.32 
246,323,743.32 
345,887.45
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,334,123.32 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,237,129.57 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,334,123.32 
2,442,887.21
255,165.11 
3,889.02 
622.43 
916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
77,245.67 
104,245.00 
332.98 
6,875.21 
12,225.14 
52.54 
402.82 
32,875.32 
183,334,123.32 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,322,555.39 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,334,123.32 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,334,123.32 
2,442,887.21
255,165.11 
3,889.02 
622.43 
916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
77,245.67 
104,245.00 
332.98 
6,875.21 
12,225.14 
52.54 
402.82 
32,875.32 
153,334,123.32 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,400,321.23 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,334,123.32 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,334,123.32 
2,442,887.21
255,165.11 
3,889.02 
622.43 
916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
77,245.67 
104,245.00 
332.98 
6,875.21 
12,225.14 
52.54 
402.82 
32,875.32 
83,334,123.32 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,341,152.99 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,334,123.32 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
139,334,123.32 
2,442,887.21
255,165.11 
3,889.02 
622.43 
916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
77,245.67 
104,245.00 
332.98 
6,875.21 
12,225.14 
52.54 
402.82 
32,875.32 
164,334,123.32 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,299,477.81 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,334,123.32 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
139,334,123.32 
2,442,887.21
255,165.11 
3,889.02 
622.43 
916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
77,245.67 
104,245.00 
332.98 
6,875.21 
12,225.14 
52.54 
402.82 
32,875.32 
166,334,123.32 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,309,926.11 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,334,123.32 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
139,334,123.32 
2,442,887.21
255,165.11 
3,889.02 
622.43 
916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
77,245.67 
104,245.00 
332.98 
6,875.21 
12,225.14 
52.54 
402.82 
32,875.32 
83,334,123.32 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,334,123.32 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
129,387,002.55 
345,887.21
16,520.11 
388,902.02 
24,622.43 
278,916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
377,245.67 
5,104,245.00 
23,332.98 
126,875.21 
5,112,225.14 
4,552.54 
402.82 
132,875.32 
31,334,123.32 
2,442,887.21
255,165.11 
3,889.02 
622.43 
916.52 
42.22 
17,234.01 
77,245.67 
104,245.00 
332.98 
6,875.21 
12,225.14 
52.54 
402.82 
32,875.32 
83,334,123.32
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that SQLite will truncate the numbers at the commas when it implicitly casts those strings to numbers so that it can SUM them. For example:

```
sqlite> select '1,000' + '2,000';
'1,000' + '2,000'
3
```

All you need to do is strip out the commas. You should be able to use [`replace`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#replace) and then let SQLite's default type conversions take it from there:

```
SELECT SUM(replace(price, ',', '')) FROM example
```

For example:

```
sqlite> select replace('1,000', ',', '') + replace('2,000', ',', '');
replace('1,000', ',', '') + replace('2,000', ',', '')
3000
```

Comment: You might want to consider removing the commas before the data gets into SQLite, all those string operations don't come cheap.